# I want to pass props to stackNavigator inside tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I am trying to pass props from login screen to the whole app because every fetch request depend on user credentials so how can I achieve this.

**routeConfig file:**

```
 export const sendStack = StackNavigator({
         send:{
             screen:Send,
         },
         confirm:{
             screen:ConfrimPay,
         }

     });
     export const transactionStack = StackNavigator({
        transaction:{
            screen:Transaction,
        },
        details:{
            screen:Details,
        }
     });
     export const Tab=TabNavigator({
         send:{
              screen:sendStack,
         },
         receivers:{
              screen:Receipt,
              tabBar:{
                   swipeEnabled:false
              }
            },
            transaction:{
                screen:transactionStack
            },
        },
        {
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            swipeEnabled: false,
            tabBarOptions: {
              activeTintColor: 'white',
              labelStyle:{
                fontSize:5
              }
            }
        } 
    );

    export const Logst =StackNavigator({

        first:{
            screen:First
        },

        login:{
            screen:App ,
        },

        tab:{
            screen:Tab,
        },
    },
    {
      headerMode: 'none',
      navigationOptions: {
        headerVisible: false,
      }
     });
```

**Root nav:**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import {Tab, Logst,Root} from './mainNav';
    import App from './App';


    class List extends Component {
      render() {
        return(<Logst  />) ;
      }
    }
```

This my login page and I use this.props.navigation.navigate('tab',{user:user,pwd:pwd}); and it's getting me an error that mean the props has not been passed

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('tab',{user:user,pwd:pwd}); 

+this.props.navigation.state.params.user+'&pwd='+this.props.navigation.state.params.pwd+'&func=2
```

Note* **I am passing props from stackNav to stackNav nested in TabNav**